# Odoo. Dynamically inject url in werkzeug

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, werkzeug, odoo-9

Odoo has way of route definition via decorators. That's almost fine, but.. we want to write module, that will allow us to do dynamic rewrites.

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/http.html - here we can find standard way of adding route.

Looks like:

```
class MyController(openerp.http.Controller):
    @route('/some_url', auth='public')
    def handler(self):
        return stuff()
```

Ideally we want to find where odoo stores `RouteMap` for `werkzeug`.

I've tried also to add decorated method to controller in way like:

```
def my_redirect(new_url):
    t = lambda x: werkzeug.utils.redirect(new_url, 301)
    return t

MyController.test = http.route('/old_url/')(my_redirect('/new_url/'))
```

But in this case we get error [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8b4f052a3872b397bbe252e353b1d18d273ec8ff/openerp/http.py#L1001).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference documentation for Odoo 9 routes is [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/http.html#reference-http-controllers), just in case.

Odoo computes and stores the web routes in the `routing_map` (computed [here in 8.0](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/1d7c12022/openerp/http.py#L805-L857), and [there in 9.0](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/c89e45358ea/openerp/http.py#L961-L1013)).
The map is lazily computed and exposed to extension modules in the `ir.http` model, through the `routing_map()` method, ([8.0](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/1d7c12022dcffce4792b9eec85706e19338cfa9f/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py#L189), [9.0](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/c89e45358e/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py#L200)). The `ir.http._find_handler()` method is called by `ir.http._dispatch()` during request handling to locate the matching route in the `routing_map`.

You could override/extend any of these to implement your own dynamic routes, similarly to how the `web` module does it.

---

**Fallback routing:** An interesting alternative for dynamically handling requests that do not match existing "static" rules is the [`_handle_exception()` method](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/c89e45358ea/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py#L143) of `ir.http`. It is called whenever an exception occurs during the request handling phase, including when no matching route is found. Anything it returns will be used as the response.

The `web` module extends it to:

- provide "user-friendly" error pages (404, 500, etc.)
- to allow users to bind arbitrary fallback routes to documents [coming from the attachments (`ir.attachment`) tables](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/c89e45358ea/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py#L112).
  This is sometimes used has a transition "hack" to map URLs from a former website.

Comment: Reviewed these ways. The only solution that currently comes in mind is to generate class with routes.. But how we can add route to `routing_map()` outside @http.route decorator?